# Can I print Object as string like Date in console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, format

When I create the new Date object and using console.log shows not object but time as string.
However, MyObject is print as Object.

Example:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date);

const MyObject = function() {
  this.name = 'Stackoverflow',
  this.desc = 'is Good'
};
console.log(new MyObject());
```

Result:

```
2017-04-06T06:28:03.393Z
MyObject { name: 'Stackoverflow', desc: 'is Good' }
```

But I want to print MyObject like below format without using function or method.

```
Stackoverflow is Good
```

In java, I can override `toString ()` to implement this.
Is it possible in javascript too?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Because `console.log` doesn't use `toString`. I've now corrected and undeleted it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, that is my typo. Thanks :)

Comment: You can also use `var obj= new MyObject();
console.log(obj.name+' '+ obj.desc);`

Comment: @JijoCleetus I want to use only MyObject in `console.log` without any properties. like this `console.log(new MyObject());` Thanks :)

Comment: you need to use the new keyword outside console log. Otherwise you need to rely on two objects like this. `console.log(new MyObject().name +' '+ new MyObject().desc);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `console.log` provides any mechanism to tell it what representation to use for the object.

You can do `console.log(String(new MyObject()));` and give `MyObject.prototype` a `toString` method:

```
const MyObject = function() {
  this.name = 'Stackoverflow';
  this.desc = 'is Good';
};
MyObject.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.name + this.desc;
};
```

As you're using ES2015+ features (I see that from `const`), you might also consider `class` syntax:

```
class MyObject {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Stackoverflow';
    this.desc = 'is Good';
  }
  toString() {
    return this.name + this.desc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tips:  in javascript ,you still can use "override" a method to impletement it

demo:

```
let myobj={id:1,name:'hello'};

Object.prototype.toString=function(){ 

   return this.id+' and '+this.name

}; //override toString of 'Global' Object.

console.log(obj.toString());// print: 1 is hello
```

Answer (score -1):

**Actually very simple:**

```
let oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function ()
{
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (arguments[i] && arguments[i].toString)
            arguments[i] = arguments[i].toString();
    oldLog.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Your object should bring a *toString* method. Might use other criteria than *toString* to decide what and how to stringify.