# Is it possible to cover a variable with a class JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-5

Suppose we have a class called `Foo()` which takes the value as an argument and has some method `method1, metohd2,...`.

```
let y = new Foo(56);
console.log(y) // output should be 56 not the class object
y.addOne() // output: adds one to the value
console.log(y) // output should be 57
```

Can we do this? Not especially with `Numbers` only, but with other datatypes too?

Comment: Your code is using ES6, is there a reason why you tagged ES5?

Comment: Where is it using ES6?

Comment: @ritaj The `let` is ES6

Comment: Generally you should only tag specific versions of a language if they are relevant to the question.

Comment: Related: [Can I print Object as string like Date in console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43247785) (I don't think what you want is possible)

Comment: I think you're trying to mimic `Class.toString` method functionality in Java. I don't think it's possible in JavaScript